# How to get basic Spark program running on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I'm trying to get off the ground with Spark and Kubernetes but I'm facing difficulties. I used the helm chart here:

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/spark

I have 3 workers and they all report running successfully. I'm trying to run the following program remotely:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://<master-ip>:<master-port>").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json('people.json')
```

Here's the part that's not entirely clear. Where should the file people.json actually live? I have it locally where I'm running the python code and I also have it on a PVC that the master and all workers can see at /sparkdata/people.json.

When I run the 3rd line as simply `'people.json'` then it starts running but errors out with:

`WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`

If I run it as `'/sparkdata/people.json'` then I get

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/sparkdata/people.json`

Not sure where I go from here. To be clear I want it to read files from the PVC. It's an NFS share that has the data files on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `people.json` file needs to be accessible to your driver + executor pods. This can be achieved in multiple ways:

- having some kind of network/cloud drive that each pod can access
- mounting volumes on your pods, and then uploading the data to those volumes using `--files` in your spark-submit.

The latter option might be the simpler to set up. [This page](https://jaceklaskowski.github.io/spark-kubernetes-book/demo/spark-and-local-filesystem-in-minikube/#hostpath) discusses in more detail how you could do this, but we can shortly go to the point. If you add the following arguments to your spark-submit you should be able to get your `people.json` on your driver + executors (you just have to choose sensible values for the $VAR variables in there):

```
  --files people.json \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=$SOURCE_DIR \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.$VOLUME_TYPE.$VOLUME_NAME.mount.path=$MOUNT_PATH \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.$VOLUME_TYPE.$VOLUME_NAME.options.path=$MOUNT_PATH \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.$VOLUME_TYPE.$VOLUME_NAME.mount.path=$MOUNT_PATH \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.$VOLUME_TYPE.$VOLUME_NAME.options.path=$MOUNT_PATH \
```

You can always verify the existence of your data by going inside of the pods themselves like so:

```
kubectl exec -it <driver/executor pod name> bash
(now you should be inside of a bash process in the pod)
cd <mount-path-you-chose>
ls -al
```

That last `ls -al` command should show you a `people.json` file in there (after having done your spark-submit of course).

Hope this helps!

Comment: YARN seems easier.

Comment: This is where I get confused. The people.json file is accessible by all the pods, I've tested that. Master and workers. When Spark is local on Windows I can just write code like the above and it will run. I don't want to use spark-submit. I want to drive the cluster programmatically. This might not even be possible though.

Comment: Hmm interesting, if it says `Path does not exist: file:/sparkdata/people.json` I would expect that your data is not accessible to the relevant pods. How have you made the json file accessible to the pods? And how did you verify that it was accessible?